# Manipulating Pointers In Assembly

Tags: pointers, assembly, x86, emu8086

I have a pointer to a matrix that I received from a C function and I need to fill another array that I had received from the same C function and I need to fill it with the sums of each columns of the matrix. The problem is that after filling the array it returns to the C function and when it tries to print the array it results in unrelated numbers(probably addresses) being printed instead of the actual sum of the columns.

Here's the code from the C function:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
extern void sum_col(int n, int m, long int *matrix[], long int new_col[]);
int main() {
    int n = 4, m = 3, i, j;
    long int *matrix[4];
    long int new_col[3];
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        matrix[i] = (long int *)malloc(m * sizeof(long int));
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < m; j++)
            matrix[i][j] = 100 * i + j;
    sum_col(n, m, matrix, new_col);
    printf("matrix:\n");
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < m; j++)  printf("%8ld", matrix[i][j]);
        printf("\n");
    } // for
    printf("new_col:\n");
    for (i = 0; i < m; i++)
        printf("%8ld", new_col[i]);
    return 0;
} // main
```

And here's the assembly code:

```
.MODEL SMALL
.DATA
SUM DW ?
I   DW ?
J   DW ?
K   DW ?
.CODE

PUBLIC _sum_col
_sum_col PROC NEAR
PUSH BP
MOV BP,SP
PUSH SI
PUSH DI

MOV I,0
MOV J,0
MOV K,0
MOV CX,[BP+6]   ; CX = m
MOV BX,[BP+4]   ; BX = n
MOV SI,[BP+8]   ; SI = matrix
MOV DI,[BP+12]  ; DI = new_col


L1:
MOV SUM,0
PUSH CX
MOV CX,BX
MOV I,0
L2:
MOV SI,[BP+8]
ADD SI,I
MOV AX,[SI]
MOV SI,AX
ADD SI,J
MOV AX,[SI]
ADD SUM,AX
ADD I,2
LOOP L2
MOV AX,SUM
ADD DI,K
MOV [DI],AX
ADD J,4
ADD K,4
POP CX
LOOP L1

POP DI
POP SI
POP BP
RET
_sum_col ENDP
END
```

Can someone tell me where I went wrong?

Comment: Your array-of-arrays entries are `long int`, 32-bit.  Your 16-bit code will need to use `add`/`adc` to sum them, with 2 16-bit registers holding a 32-bit sum.  Have you single-stepped your code with a debugger to see if you're accessing the data even close to correctly?  Why is there static storage for `I,J,K`?  Your function gets the array dimensions as args, there's no need to keep locals in static storage like that.  (Use registers, or reserve some stack space.)

Comment: @PeterCordes Yeah I debugged it and it seems to access the right addresses but only after a few hundred alterations to the code and it even shows that [DI] has the right values but when it gets to printing it messes them up. Is there any other reason why this could be happening?